# How to debug C program with argument and stdin as input

Tags: c, gdb

I want to debug a C program.

```
./test 1 2 3 << end
Monos(1,2)
Monos(6)
end
```

How to debug this?

Comment: what do you mean ? `Monos(1,2)` and `Monos(6)` are the inputs of the program ? If yes start _gdb_ (or _ddd_) on your program, place breakpoints, run and enter the input by hand when needed depending on the execution / breakpoints

Comment: You need the GDB documentation, not SO.

Comment: you need to attach that running process to debugger and configure some break point location in code and wait until that debugger to hit break point location

Comment: I am not sure it is good to add youtube video link here. You can use this video as a reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7L2x1ATOgk

Comment: @IanAbbott no, `< end' redirect the input from the file _end_, here the input will give the next lines upto the word _end_ (_end_ is not given of course)

Comment: <<end Monos(1,2) Monos(6) end is the part interactive with the program, it’s the shell input, not limit the size of  input, Monos(1,2) Monos(6) is the key part, they are strings

Comment: What I have tried gdb —args ./test 1 2 3 then run < Monos(1,2) Monos(6), but it doesn’t work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For easier debugging with GDB, you should convert the "here string" lines between the `<<end` and `end` into a text file (say "input.txt").  Then, in `gdb` you can use the `set args` command to set up the command-line arguments and redirection of standard input from the file.

For example: suppose the file "input.txt" contains:

```
Monos(1,2)
Monos(6)
```

Run `gdb` from the shell as follows:

```
$ gdb ./test
```

Within GDB, set the command-line arguments and redirection of standard input:

```
(gdb) set args 1 2 3 < input.txt
```

Set any breakpoints, e.g.:

```
(gdb) b main
```

And start running the code:

```
(gdb) r
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this redirection on the gdb command-line, but instead do it on the `run` command inside gdb.

https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Input_002fOutput.html#Input_002fOutput

Comment: Thanks for your help